# Jsoup - parse a simple <div>

Tags: jquery, html, jsoup

I have the following html part:

```
<div class="share-btn print-btn">
  <a href="etc" target="print_169471" rel="nofollow" class="bottom_tooltip empty" title="Print the article"><i class="print"></i></a>
</div>
```

from which i would like to extract only the link under href attr.
I tried using my code:

```
    Document mainDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://main-html").get();

    Elements newsHeadlines = mainDoc.select(".share-btn print-btn");

    String printLink = newsHeadlines.attr("href");
    System.out.println(printLink);
```

where main-html includes the part I showed above, but it doesn't work. I guess the issue is on ".share-btn print-btn"; maybe Jsoup selects only the first string, which is not viable; so I would need to select both strings in order to obtain the link under "href" tag.

Comment: You're selecting the div (incorrectly), you're not doing anything to iterate over the link contained in the div's child elements. The div doesn't have an "href" attribute.

Comment: try with : mainDoc.select(".share-btn.print-btn");